# Use a Clementine smart playlist to show duplicate songs

Tags: 12.04, files, delete, clementine, duplicate-files

After switching to Ubuntu, I discovered iTunes had been storing duplicates of my music.

e.g.

`Highway to Hell/` contains:

```
Highway to Hell.mp3
Highway to Hell 1.mp3
Girls Got Rhythm.mp3
Girls Got Rhythm 1.mp3 ...etc
```

Not *all* of my music is like this, only some of it.

My question is, is there a way I can create a smart playlist that:

1) Finds if an album has duplicate tracks

2) Finds if any of the duplicate track end in " 1.mp3"

3) Select only those tracks for the playlist.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to delete/remove these duplicate files?

Comment: Yea, but deleting them is trivial.  The hard (time-consuming) part is selecting them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing FSLint!

To install from terminal Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install fslint`

To install from Software Center, Search for 'fslint'.

It can easily find duplicate files and then gives you an option to delete, Move etc. Give it the path to your iTunes folder, and click find.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I am trying this out right now. It will take awhile since my music folder is about 200gb.

Comment: Good to know! FSLint checks if the files are *exactly* the same, so if one is say an MP3 and the other is an M4A, or they have different bitrates, it will *not* consider them duplicates. If you have this problem, please update and I'll find a solution :)   Please select this as the answer if it all works out.

Answer (score 0):

Quodlibet (music player/library manager) has a duplicate plugin to find duplicates tracks sharing the same tags (artist, title, length, anything..). So, if your library is properly tagged, your duplicate files should have the same tags. And being a music player, you could more easily listen/delete/rename tracks. You can also set any pattern of tag you want, if for example, the artist tag is missing ..